# Get Property of Object from array it is in

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a `NSObject` class called `Post`. A `post` has the property `URL`. When my application starts new posts are created with URLs and added to an array called _objects. When a table cell is selected I want to set something to `post.url` in `_objects[indexPath.row]`.

Adding to the table:

```
NSMutableArray *newPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
for (SomeElement *element in postNodes) {

    Post *post = [[Post alloc] init];
    [newPosts addObject:post];

    post.title = [[element firstChild] content];

    post.url = [element objectForKey:@"href"];
}

_objects = newPosts;
```

If I call `_objects[indexPath.row]` when a cell is selected it returns  or something simular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
Post *post = _objects[indexPath.row];
[something setURL:post.url];
```

You could also make it a little bit more efficient by replacing the first line in your code snippet with this:

```
NSMutableArray *newPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:postNodes.count];
```

This will preallocate enough space in the array to hold all your posts.